# SQL запрос (GROUP BY, HAVING), выборка с одним типом записей

Tags: sql

Есть такая таблица воздушных судов:

```
ak_code bnum        craft_type
AA      RA-85205    T154
AA      RA-85162    T154
AA      RA-26305    AN26
BB      RA-85343    T154
CC      RA-96002    IL96
CC      RA-96012    IL96
CC      RA-96016    IL96
```

Мне надо одним запросом получить такие авиакомпании (`ak_code`), у которых есть более одного борта (bnum), но при этом все суда только одного типа (craft_type).

Пока придумал только это:

```
select ak_code,craft_type from crafts
 where ak_code in(
   select ak_code from crafts
    group by ak_code
   having count(bnum)>1
 )
group by ak_code,craft_type
```

в результате чего получаем:

```
ak_code  craft_type
AA       AN26
AA       T154
CC       IL96
```

Правильным должно быть

```
ak_code  craft_type
CC       IL96
```

Подскажите, я на волоске от правильного решения или совсем не в ту сторону ушел? -_-

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(model)>1` или `HAVING COUNT(maker)>1`?

Comment: Так же голосую за закрытие. Полностью согласен с @msi. Вопрос в принципе уместный, если его сформулировать в общем виде, а не просто как задачу с sql-ex.

Comment: @pegoopik так и сделали, можете вернуть плюс)

Comment: Не думал что вопрос будет на столько интересным. Тем временем меня забанили на sql-ex :D кажется кто - то ябида)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, другое дело:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Что то в этом роде:

```
select ak_code,craft_type from crafts
 where ak_code in(
   select ak_code from crafts
    group by ak_code
   having count(bnum)>1                 -- Количество бортов более 1 (аналогично count(1))
      and count(distinct craft_type)=1  -- Только один уникальный тип ВС
 )
group by ak_code,craft_type
```

Но если дословно следовать тексту и нужны только авиакомпании, то внутреннего подзапроса достаточно самого по себе. Внешний запрос уже выводит типы судов по найденным авиакомпаниям.

**update**: по предложениям [pegoopik](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199437/pegoopik)

```
select ak_code,max(craft_type) from crafts
 group by ak_code
having count(bnum)>1
   and max(craft_type)=min(craft_type)
```

Comment: count(distinct type) не самый лучший способ решения. Нам не нужно знать количество уникальных типов - а это сортировка, которой можно избежать.

Comment: @pegoopik предложите способ избежать. на простейшем диалекте sql, потому как БД не указана

Comment: MIN(type) = MAX(type). Это один проход по группе, в отличии от COUNT + DISTINCT, который приводит к сортировке. И в SELECT'е можно написать MAX(type) для вывода типа, вместо того, чтобы делать подзапрос с IN.

Comment: @pegoopik Не думал что min/max делаются сильно по другому, но оракл говорит что да, стоимость гораздо ниже. не знаю как на других субд. условия вывести тип не заметил, вообще не понимал зачем внешний запрос, думал ТС так надо